# Storing list in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I want to save a friends list in Cassandra where a user may have few hundred of friends  .  Should i store the list of friends, which is an email id, as a list or set in Cassandra or should i create a separate table having the columns user_id and friends which will include all the user(millions of users) along with their friends .

If i create a separate table with user_id and friends column will there be degradation in performance while retrieving the entire friend list of the user/ one friend of the user as the table will contain many records/rows.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that `lists` and `sets` in Cassandra are not iterable.  This means when you query for them, you get back the whole list or the whole set.  If the collection has a high cardinality then this could pose issues in querying such as read timeouts or even a heap OOM error.

Since it sounds like there is no cap on the amount of friends one can have, one option could be to have a separate table that is partitioned on user and clustered on friend.

```
CREATE TABLE user_friends (
  owner_user_id int,
  friend_user_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY(owner_user_id, friend_user_id)
);
```

This will ensure that the friend_user_id is in order and will allow you to do client side paging if the number of friends is very large.  It also allows for a quick way to check if a person is a friend of a user.